# Integrating d3 with a custom angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am working on an application that uses angular to keep data coming in from a few different services in sync and to hand this data off to some d3 functions to generate graphics and tables.

Right now, I'm having difficulty getting the data bound at the correct level within the d3 code. I'm creating a basic table at this point.

Here is my directive:

```
application.directive('d3table', function() {
   var chart = table();
   return  {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
        data: "="
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watchCollection('data', function(data) {
               d3.select(element[0]).datum(data).call(chart);
           });
       }
   }
});
```

My d3 code for table() is as follows, using the [toward reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) approach:

```
function tableChart() {
    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function(dataset) {
            var table = d3.select(this).append('table');

            table.append('thead').append('tr')
              .selectAll('tr').data(columns).enter()
              .append('th').text(function(d) { return d;});
    }
    return chart;
}
```

The data I am working here is a simple array. Data is added and removed periodically.

The issue I am having is that instead of updating the existing table, the appending of data is triggering the generation of a new table. So I end up with multiple tables, instead of one which is properly bound to the d3 function.

Comment: every time the chart function is ran it appends a table the existing element. So each time data changes in your collection its creating a new table. I would just edit the function to append just the thead, tr and th elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the table beforehand.

```
function tableChart() {
    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function(dataset) {
            //remove existing table
            d3.select(this).select("table").remove();

            var table = d3.select(this).append('table');

            table.append('thead').append('tr')
              .selectAll('tr').data(columns).enter()
              .append('th').text(function(d) { return d;});
    }
    return chart;
}
```

Comment: Yep, this works. I was hoping to do something where the element persisted and was updated in place...but good enough is good enough. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to use remove you can also check by evaluating `d3.select(this).select("table").empty()` if it's true then append all of your elements else select and modify them.

Answer (score 0):

I Would use a template and just basically have your table and table head info in there then in the link function you can get a reference to the table. Then in the watch collection function your only adding or removing rows, not trying to recreate the whole table each time. This approach will work as long as your data scheme stays the same.

Here is some code to look at

```
//js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'D3 Angular Table';

  $scope.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];


  $scope.add = function(){
    console.log('add');
    $scope.data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) );
  };

   $scope.remove = function(){
    console.log("remove")
     $scope.data.splice(0, 1)
  };
});




app.directive('d3table', function() {
   //var chart = table();
   return  {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
        data: "="
       },
      templateUrl: 'd3table.html',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

           var table = element[0].firstChild;

           scope.$watchCollection('data', function(data) {

             var selectedTable = d3.select(table).selectAll('tr').data(data);

              selectedTable.enter()
              .append("tr")
              .text(function(d){return d});

              selectedTable.exit().remove();

           });
       }
   }
});
//html
<table id = "test" >
  <thead>
     <tr><th>Value</th></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

working plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/hb6t9gshXBngApUGyJkN?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this...The issue is that the data structure will be changing based on user activity. I'm not a ran of the d3.remove() approach, but I think it will be easier to dynamically generate the data going that route.

Comment: Ya the solution I posted isnt the best for a data structure that changes, is there any reason in particular that you favor using d3 for generating the tables, rather than using nested ng-repeats?

Comment: Mostly b/c I have a set of existing d3 functions that I've used to generate views of data in this structure and I would prefer to re-use those. Thanks for the suggestions though.